# Do all gear affixes lose effect if that gear hits zero durability?

Tags: diablo-iii

Whether we're talking set affixes, legendary affixes or any other regular affixes.

For example, if my Aquila Cuiras gives me 50% damage reduction when I'm at > 90% resource, but that equipped item is damaged down to zero durability, do I lose the conditional damage reduction as well as the 'regular affixes' (like primary stat, attack speed, armour, etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  When gear reaches 0% durability, all bonuses it would normally generate are disabled.